# Do I have to pay Oracle to use Java?

Tags: java

Do I have to pay oracle if I use Java to code a app that I will eventually monetize?

It will be a android app/game for the google play store.

Comment: You need to pay google if the app charges for anything.

Comment: Only if you distribute through Google's channels, @Sotirios.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-141681.html#D1

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta So if you had an in-app store, you wouldn't have to?

Comment: I don't know what the Play store policy is for DLC, but if I make my app available from other stores, or just on my website, Google doesn't get a cut of anything, @Sotirios.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Oh, that's not what I meant.

Comment: I asked about JAVA specifically. So are you saying that if I distribute through Googles channels, that I will have to pay to use JAVA? So I have to get a like a JAVA lincense? @Michael

Comment: You don't need a license to use Java. You need to work with Google to distribute Android apps (written with Java or some other language) through the Google Play store. Nothing specific to Java.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licence fees and software pricing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java is free, open source product; you do not need to pay Oracle for using Java.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Teeg Are you crazy? This provides an exact answer to the question. Please don't mindlessly review "low quality posts" and actually read the answers in context to the question.

Comment: @mikeyaworski Calm yourself, good sir. I agree, an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 23):

No, you don't need to pay Oracle for using Java.

Comment: i love this kind of answers with high score xD stackoverflow magic

Answer (score 3):

Oracle remains committed to **OpenJDK** as the best **open-source** Java implementation